# SQL query to find reminders for the given period for google reminders

Tags: mysql, data-modeling, datamodel

I am trying for a table design and logic for  appointment similar to google calendar reminders.

Requirement is to store single and repeated reminders for multiple users and find reminders for the given time period so as to view in the calendar.

**Table:-** appointment

```
appointment_id,
user_id,
start_date,
end_date,   --> End date for the repeat reminder. Null means never ending
start_time,
end_time
```

**Table:-** appointment_frequency

```
appointment_id,
frequency_type,  --> D(Daily),W(Weekly),M(Monthly),Y(Yearly)
interval, --> Every 3 days, Every 2 weeks, Every 4 Months, ...
sunday, --> Weekly interval that happens on Sundays
monday,
tuesday,
wednesday,
thursday,
friday,
saturday, --> Weekly interval that happens on Saturdays
on_day,   --> On 5th day of each Month, ...
on_week,  --> On 1st week of each Month, On 2nd week of each month
on_last_week, --> On last week of the month
max_repeat. --> Maximum repeat time
```

Is there any better way to store this?

Now, I need to find the reminders for the given period?
Say, Find reminders between October 1st and 15th for user 1 & 2.

I am currently, fetching all the reminders for a user and then running a java code to find reminders b/w the period. Is there any way to get using SQL query?

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b540da/5

The output I am looking for is,

```
reminder_id, user_id, name, Date, Start_time, End_time
```

For the daily reminder with no end date,

When I say, give me reminders b/w 10/15/21 and 10/12/21,

it has to return multiple entries since the daily reminder will occur everyday in the calendar.

Comment: You do not have any `usr_id=5` in your fiddle , you have `appointment_id=5`

Comment: You  are trying something like this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/115 ?

Comment: My requirement is not to get the reminder as it is in DB. Just updated the expecetd output.

Comment: You could achieve that by creating a PROCEDURE if its an option

Comment: I would go with Java than procedure. Checking if there this can be achieved with query.

Comment: Id think your best bet would be to use java to iterate through a loop for each day between 2 dates and build your query with UNION, then execute that query once.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you please share the Union query that your thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

You could either create a `PROCEDURE` within mysql OR you could use Java (since thats the programming language you mentionned in the comments) to loop through the date range and create a `UNION` query and running it once.

```
String sqlstatement = "";

for (LocalDate date = startDate; date.isBefore(endDate); date = date.plusDays(1))
{
    sqlstatement += "SELECT a.appointment_id as reminder_id, a.usr_id as user_id, '"+date+"' as date, a.st_time as Start_time, a.end_time as End_time FROM appointment a LEFT JOIN appointment_frquency af ON a.appointment_id = af.appointment_id WHERE '"+date+"' >= a.st_date AND '"+date+"' <= a.end_date UNION";
}

sqlstatement = sqlstatement.substring(0, sqlstatement.lastIndexOf(" UNION"));
```

After the for loop you'll need to strip the last UNION from the string and then you can run your query.

Comment: This is good but the query will become very big with unions this way for 1 month period and not sure if there is any limit on the query chars limit.